# Dual monitors on Debian

Tags: debian, nvidia, xrandr, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I have a desktop PC with a HDMI monitor connected to a nvidia GeForce GT 1030 and a second VGA monitor connected to an integrated Intel UHD Graphics 630.

Both monitors have worked smoothly for years with Ubuntu 18.04

I recently installed Lubuntu 22.04 on the same PC and both monitors were automatically activated without problems.

But now, in Debian 11 (with LXQt desktop) the HDMI monitor is the only one that turns on. The VGA monitor only displays text at boot and then goes in to sleep mode.

On Debian lspci says everything is allright:

```
root@debian:/home/cesar# lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
        DeviceName: Onboard - Video
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP108 [GeForce GT 1030]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia
```

And for xrandr there's no error message either, but the Intel integrated graphics card simply doesn't exist:

```
root@debian:/home/cesar# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Please give me some suggestions on where to keep looking. I've tried several proposals, but none has worked so far

Comment: @Peregrino69 I've tried both controllers nvidia and noveau. The same result, the VGA monitor receives no signal from Debian

Comment: @Peregrino69 It's not a hardware problem because I have Lubuntu and Debian installed with dual boot. With Lubuntu everything works automatically. Not with Debian.

Comment: Nvidia.... Bad news. It will not work. I tried it with similar situation (old nvidia cards + four monitor, centos 7->Mint 21, partial success => new hardware), a lot of effort for nothing. You need to use the old X system, or forget the old nvidia cards.

Comment: @K-att- Exactly the same configuration, with the same nvidia card works right now with Lubuntu 22.04. So it's not hardware problem

Comment: Yes, it is not a hardware problem. It's based on the old binary driver and the new X windows system. That's why Linus told to Nvidia........ You know, what.

Comment: @K-att- Change the hardware is not an option. I can choose the distro, and after years using Ubuntu, I want to change to Debian.  I just have to replicate on Debian what Ubuntu does smoothly , but I need help doing it

Comment: FYI: `https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237248`

Comment: @K-att- On that link they complain that the Nvidia card doesn't work anymore with a 2018 update. My Nvidia card works flawlessly on both Ubuntu and Debian.  My problem is VGA monitor connected to Intel integrated graphics card not activating as secondary monitor.  It's Intel my problem, not Nvidia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144445/discussion-between-cesargastonec-and-k-att).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easy (very hard to find, very easy to implement), thanks to:
https://askubuntu.com/a/821031/638413

The technical explanation is [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html).

My case was even easier, I didn't need to create the xorg.conf file.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Install the nvidia driver according to the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).
- In the user account, create the xsessionrc file:

  ```
  vi ~/.xsessionrc
  ```

  With the following content:

  ```
  xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
  xrandr --auto
  ```